# What is wrong with this html code?

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="float: left">text1</div> 
<div style="float: right;">text2</div>
<div class="random_class">text3</div>
```

Here is the problem. Random_class goes to the top, on the text1 and text2. What is wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Try to be more precise about what you expected to see and what you actually see.

Comment: what style is associated with random_class? Any? With no style associated with random_class, I see what I'd expect with text3 appearing between text1 and text2.

Comment: Typically, I would expect "text1" on the left, "text2" on the right, and "text3" to the right of "text1", not on top of anything...

Comment: To get your code cleaner and maintainable, you can (should) create a separated style sheet and define IDs and Classes there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to clear the floats, below is an example of it.

```
<div class="random_class" style="clear:both">text3</div>
```

You could also do

```
.random_class {
    clear: both
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/q4CqZ/3/

Added `clear:both;` to `.random_class`

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you float an element it takes it out of content flow.

Text1 and Text2 are floated so Text3 acts like it doesn't see it there.  Floats are aware of other floats. Using `clear:both;` tells CSS that nothing should be to the left or right of it.